# обработчик событий javafx при выделение текста

Tags: javafx, события, обработка

*Не так давно начал пробовать программировать не только в консоли но и  в интерфейсе. решил учиться JavaFx. Столкнулся с проблемой с обработчиками событий.*

Мне нужно что бы при выделении текста происходило событие (в моем случае вызов другого окна). Как это сделать?

Comment: Код, сударь, покажите хоть какой-то код,  пожалуйста )

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, алгоритм таков:
В JavaFx есть волшебные Properties, которые отвечают за разные свойства контрола. В частности, нашлось и propertie отвечающее за выделенный текст. Лучше посмотреть на примере:

Допустим, есть некое окно с текстовой областью, и лейблом, куда мы выведем выделенный текст:
- Волшебное творение ScieneBuilder 2.0: **TestFXML.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="571.0" />
      <Text fill="#868686" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="359.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Тест выделения текста, ничего лишнего" />
      <Text layoutX="14.0" layoutY="378.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Выделено:" />
      <Text fx:id="selectionLabel" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="378.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

И контроллер + FX Application в одном лице (см. комментарии в коде - всё самое интересное там):

```
package exp;

// Это импорты, так что тут ничего интересного
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//стандартная конструкция - класс, наследуемый от JavaFX Application
public class JavaFXSelectionListener extends Application {

    @FXML
    //Текстовая метка, отображающая выделенный текст
    private Text selectionLabel;

    @FXML
    //Текстовая область, в которую вводится текст, и отрабатывает выделение
    private TextArea textArea;

    @FXML
    //метод инициализации - почти как конструктор, но отрабатывает после(!) загрузки .fxml, и ты не ловишь NullPointer
    void initialize() {
        //JavaFX Property, отвечающее за выделенный текст. Поддерживает слушатели
        textArea.selectedTextProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            //нас интересует слушатель изменения данных свойства - т.е. выделенного текста
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                //как только выделенный текст изменился, отображаем выделение в текстовой метке
                selectionLabel.setText(textArea.selectedTextProperty().getValue());
            }
        });
    }

    //main, ничего необычного
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    //волшебный start из JavaFX Application
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            //.fxml файл должен лежать рядом с контроллером, в противном случае, путь к нему будет уже другой!
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TestFXML.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Selection Listener Test");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //если что-то пошло не так, мы узнаем об этом.
            System.out.println(String.format("Сценарий построения интерфейса повреждён, или отсутствует. Сообщение ошибки:\n%s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```